# swift search contents of local HTML files via search bar and display results in tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a very simple iOS swift app (storyboards) that displays a tableView controller to show a list of items, let's say in this case a list of fruits (Bananas, Cherries, Strawberries, Grapes, Pears).

Tapping on any table cell opens another viewController, loading a webView which displays a local HTML page (located in a directory within the app) of formatted content with respect to that item. So if you tape on "Bananas", it will load a local HTML file with a ton of formatted content regarding Bananas.

I am trying to add a search bar to the tableView controller to allow me to search the *contents* all of the HTML files within the app for a particular string, and returning a filtered tableView list including only those results that match the string appearing in the end HTML files.

For example, the HTML pages for "Cherries" and "Strawberries" contain the word "red," so if I search for "red" via the search bar, the tableView would filter and only show "Cherries" and "Strawberries" because only those pages have the search term in their respective HTML contents.

Basically, I am trying to make a very simple search engine within the app.

There are a ton of tutorials about how to filter a tableView based on search bar, but those only talk about filtering by the Label, not by the end content.

Is something like this even possible? I don't know where to start.

Trying to avoid databases or anything too complicated as it is a very simple app that just needs a basic content search feature.

Comment: You should start by showing the code that you have. And, if you have working code that allows filtering by the "Label" as you say, show that. It sounds like it should be a simple matter of switching which piece of your model the filter acts on, but without any code, it's impossible to say.